# Merging unequal dataframe with all values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I want to merge the two data frames with unequal lengths with some conditions. The details of the data frames are:

1. Dataframe A contains approx 1000 rows
2. Dataframe B contains approx 50 rows

The fields in both the data frame are similar like
in A:

```
A_Name, A_count, A_Normalised value, A_year
```

Dataframe A:

```
print (df1)
   A_Organisation  A_count  A_Normalised  A_Year
0             ABC      654         34545    2018
1             DEF      565         54564    2018
2             GHI      565         34546    2018
3             QWE      790          3945    2018
4             DSO      788          1561    2017
5             DFB    34579           546    2017
6             HHS       56         31651    2017
7            FDGH       98           156    2016
8            DSFH    51651        153156    2016
9            KBIU      151          1561    2015
10            SDF      165          6513    2015
```

For Dataframe B:

```
B_Name, B_count, B_Normalised value, B_year

print (df2)
  B_Organisation  B_count  B_Normalised  B_Year
0            MNO      123           432    2018
1            MNO      133           234    2018
2            MNO     8743           484    2017
3            MNO     1335          1512    2015
4            MNO      456          3454    2014
5            MNO      345           234    2014
```

Now, I want to merge both the data frame based on year, but I don't want duplicate values.
i.e. if in Dataframe A, let's say for 2018, contains 50 values and in Dataframe B, for 2018, contains 5 values. Then the total rows for 2018 should be 50 and the output should be like:

[image]

Comment: You've shown the output, but the corresponding input would also be quite helpful.

Comment: joining just on year is going to create a many to many relationship where each row in either dataframe is going to match multiple rows on either side of the join and multiply your results. You're going to need to join on multiple criteria to remove duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter columns, then [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `rename` columns for avoid columns with same content `A_Year` and `B_Year` if used parameters `left_on` and `right_on` in `merge`:

```
df1['g'] = df1.groupby('A_Year').cumcount()
df2['g'] = df2.groupby('B_Year').cumcount()

df = (df1.rename(columns={'A_Year':'Year'})
         .merge(df2.rename(columns={'B_Year':'Year'}), on=['Year','g'], how='outer')
         .drop('g', axis=1))
```

---

```
print (df)
   A_Organisation  A_count  A_Normalised  Year B_Organisation  B_count  \
0             ABC    654.0       34545.0  2018            MNO    123.0   
1             DEF    565.0       54564.0  2018            MNO    133.0   
2             GHI    565.0       34546.0  2018            NaN      NaN   
3             QWE    790.0        3945.0  2018            NaN      NaN   
4             DSO    788.0        1561.0  2017            MNO   8743.0   
5             DFB  34579.0         546.0  2017            NaN      NaN   
6             HHS     56.0       31651.0  2017            NaN      NaN   
7            FDGH     98.0         156.0  2016            NaN      NaN   
8            DSFH  51651.0      153156.0  2016            NaN      NaN   
9            KBIU    151.0        1561.0  2015            MNO   1335.0   
10            SDF    165.0        6513.0  2015            NaN      NaN   
11            NaN      NaN           NaN  2014            MNO    456.0   
12            NaN      NaN           NaN  2014            MNO    345.0   

    B_Normalised  
0          432.0  
1          234.0  
2            NaN  
3            NaN  
4          484.0  
5            NaN  
6            NaN  
7            NaN  
8            NaN  
9         1512.0  
10           NaN  
11        3454.0  
12         234.0
```